# Glade Ubuntu Error (Python)

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, glade

I am making an application using glade and python in Ubuntu. I used the about dialog widget to make an about page that is accessed via a drop down menu. When I open this about dialog the first time it works fine. When I close it with the 'x' in the top left corner it will not reopen. I have my 'delete-event' signal bound to a function close_about_window() which looks like this.

`def close_about_window(self, *args):`

`---- self.about_window.hide()`

Also if anyone knows the signal for the "close" button located at the bottom of the screen by license and credits that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to the problem is really simple. I realized that a dialog box is not the same as a window. You want to show the window using .run() not .show_all() or .show(). Use .run() and then in the same function use .hide(). Your open_about_dialog() function will look like this.

```
def open_about_dialog():
    self.about_dialog.run()
    self.about_dialog.hide()
```

Just so there is no issue I imported my object from my glade file using the builder `builder.get_object("about_dialog")`

Comment: You can show the window using `show_all()`; in this case, though, your code returns immediately and you are responsible for handling `response` AND the `delete-event` yourself. You have to do the latter too because GtkWindow's default `delete-event` destroys the window, and GtkDialog inherits from GtkWindow without overriding that. In fact, this is probably the bug with your original code: `delete-event` requires you to return a boolean value that decides whether the default handler (that is, GtkWindow's) gets run or not, and you're not doing that. IDK how it works in Python though, sorry.

Comment: (`GtkDialog.run()` provides its own handlers for `response` and `delete-event`, as the GTK+ documentation points out.)

Comment: Yes thank you. I figured that the delete event was destroying the window even though I didn't write that in. I only now thought to check the parent.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can set response id's to buttons in Glade also. `-3` is Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT and `-6` is Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL. This saves a lot of hand written code.

Comment: You should avoid `.run()` though as it creates another mainloop.

Comment: Invoking the run method to receive the response code or handling the callbacks from dialog buttons seems irrelevant and left to the programmer choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the About page is a Dialog, when you run the dialog you can connect a callback to the **response** signal and you will get a response_id.

The body of your callback could be something like this:

```
if (response_id == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL || response_id == Gtk.ResponseType.DELETE_EVENT) {
    dialog.hide_on_delete ();
}
```

You also have the Dialog **close** signal which will work for keybindings, let's say, pressing ESC.

Comment: The `response` signal will cover everything, including keybindings.

Comment: yes it will, it's just a note to that signal existence. Thanks @andlabs

Comment: You only set `hide_on_delete()` once, not in the callback.

Comment: @TingPing [Check this](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.hide_on_delete.html) and check the about dialog [example](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.AboutDialog.html).

Comment: No problem @TingPing It also improves the discussion. GL Peace